# Copy selected text from Microsoft Edge using User32 PInvoke Api

Tags: c#, .net, user32

I am writing C# application to Copy selected text from any window.
I have written following code, it is working fine for all window but not working for Microsoft edge.

```
private static string GetSelectedTextFromWindow(IntPtr handle)
{
      SetForegroundWindow(handle);
      KeyBoard(0x11, 0, 0, 0);
      KeyBoard(0x43, 0, 0, 0);
      KeyBoard(0x11, 0, 0x2, 0);
      KeyBoard(0x43, 0, 0x2, 0);

      System.Threading.Thread.Sleep(600);

      string content = System.Windows.Forms.Clipboard.GetText();
      return content;
}

[DllImport("user32.dll")]
private static extern bool SetForegroundWindow(IntPtr hwld);

[DllImport("user32", EntryPoint = "keybd_event", CharSet = CharSet.Ansi, SetLastError = true, ExactSpelling = true)]
private static extern long keybd_event(byte bVk, byte bScan, long dwFlags, long dwExtraInfo);

private static long KeyBoard(byte b, byte c, long d, long e)
{
     return keybd_event(b, c, d, e);
}
```

Comment: Doesn't Edge have some sort of sandboxing ?

Comment: Yes, Edge has sandboxing.

Comment: I guess you've answered your own question then !

Comment: Yes may be. But I am confused because I can resize, move also able send keys to Edge using same api. Then why only copy command is not working.

Comment: Driving an application is one thing, copying potentially sensitive data is another thing, i.e. it's at the discretion of the application you are targeting.

Comment: Or maybe you are specifying a wrong window handle in GetSelectedTextFromWindow. You should send the keys to a window with class name: ApplicationFrameInputSinkWindow, which is a child window of the Edge's main window with class name = ApplicationFrameWindow.